# Is it ok to use base class attribute in the initialization list?

Tags: c++

I have a class which has an attribute whose value depends on an attribute from its base class. This base class attribute is modified in the constructor so that I need its value after being modified. I tried to summarize the idea in this example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int att_a;
    A(int x) : att_a(x) {
        att_a++;
    }; // att_a is being modified in the constructor of A
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    std::string att_b; // att_b is from a different type than att_a but its value is obtained from att_a
    B(int y) : A(y), att_b(std::to_string(att_a)) {};
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    B b = B(3);
    std::cout << b.att_b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using attribute `att_a` from `class A`, which was modified during it's construction, as an input to a function that initializes `att_b` of `class B`. My concerns are:

- Is that a good way of accomplishing what I want?
- Even though it compiles and run, can it cause undefined behavior under certain circumstances?

Comment: The construction order is fully defined. Base class will be fully constructed before member initialization of derived class. So what you're doing is fine

Comment: I'm pretty sure that evaluation of the initializer for a member is sequenced after the initialization of the previous member, which would make this code correct

Comment: @Rostislav mere construction order is not sufficient, e.g. perhaps `a( f() ), b( g() )` might be allowed to call `f` and `g` in either order , so long as `a`'s constructor is then invoked before `b`'s .  I think there is *also* text in the standard that says it cannot call `g()` before finishing constructing `a` but not sure exactly where

Comment: @M.M that is indeed something to be concerned. For me the most logical order would be (f, a, g, b) but I'm not sure if the standard guarantees it.

Comment: @M.M I think I understand your question - it is basically 'is there a sequence point between initialization expressions in constructor member initialization' - is it correct? Had to look it up but seems rule 1 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), that `an initializer expression (ends with a comma or semicolon) [...]  is sequenced before each value computation and side effect of the next full expression`, so it seems like there's a sequence point between the initializer expressions. But would be interesting to see the actual standardeze support for this.

Comment: well, `f()` doesn't end with a comma, it ends with a `)` .  And `a(f())` isn't an expression. I don't see anything in 12.6.2 about sequencing either. There is a note with an example that assumes this sequencing, but notes are non-normative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can it cause undefined behaviour?

  No.

  When using a member initialization list, the order is fully defined: First base-classes in their order, then members in their order. So at the time you create any member, all base classes and all previous declared members are instantiated. If you switch the order in your constructor, your compiler should output a warning.
- Is it a good way of accomplishing what you want?

  Since you don't tell us what you are going to do with those classes, i can't tell you if its a good way, but you can do it this way if it fits your needs.